# angularjs animate : how to have an instantaneous ng-show (without fade in) while the hide does a fade out

Tags: angularjs

In need a directive that does an instantaneous show (without 
fade in), and when it gets hidden (ng-show='false'), does a progressive
fade out.

here is my attempt :

http://plnkr.co/edit/bEzAlwjNOsxLodnawu3s?p=preview

```
<span ng-show="inProgress" class="animate-fade">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
    <span ng-if="inProgress">save in progress...</span>
    <span ng-if="! inProgress">saved</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new animation class and define `.new-anim` to appear, and `.new-anim-remove.new-anim-remove-active` class selector to animate, although this would require you to use the $animate service.